# Why do power supply module's capacitor and inductor blow up?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, inductor

I developed a power supply module. The instant I connected the PCB to mains, the capacitor and inductor blew up. Does anyone know how to debug the problem?

The ratings of the components are good enough to handle the voltage from mains.  The inductor current is 1.9 A, but is that the issue here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: "*The ratings of the components are good enough to handle the voltage from mains.*" But are they? Are we supposed to take your word for it and assume that you did not do something like think a 150V rated capacitor can handle a 120VAC line?

Comment: which capacitor you are referring to? @DKNguyen

Comment: C1 for example, but anything really. Which brings up another issue with your question: You did not specify which capacitor you blew up.

Comment: L1 is rated for 80 V only, the 10 ohm 1206 resistor cannot carry the inrush current, the regulation PWM will come too late to adjust the voltage.

Comment: C1 is R463I333040H2M, yes L1 voltage is misjudged true. I will replace the L1 and 10ohm resistor with full circuit in place rather than just testing the voltage at input pins for the transformer.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an isolated (or earth referenced) power supply? I see the same ground symbol and netname "GND" on both the primary and secondary side.

Comment: Yes, this is an isolated power supply. Care was taken that components on primary and secondary have different GND

Comment: I have no idea how, or even if, you have managed to keep the two grounds isolated, but the schematic is incredibly confusing to read.  What's going on with opto-coupler Q4, it cannot possibly be right?

Comment: AUX_VOL is an AC signal and cannot feed a linear regulator, ENABLE_TS of primary circuit is fed from +5 of secondary circuit !!, HCPL181 diode and transistor are exchanged, circuit around Q2 has no function, C13, C14 1 uF only?!

Comment: Short circuit of secondary winding SEC2, remove connection of transformer pin 16.

Comment: Sorry to be that guy, but are you in over your head for a mains powered supply? Have you done any prior SMPS designs? Have you simulated or calculated anything?

Comment: Please add the technical info in your comments to your question.  Please explain how you preceive how your design is supposed to work. Post ratings of components.

Comment: This is my first design in mains powered supply.

Comment: Any suggestions where I can learn more to make the design better

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what else is wrong, but that [10 Ω resistor](https://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/YAGEO/RT1206FRE1310RL?qs=Fz%2FrpjPuTcE0F6oS7uLC7w%3D%3D) is only rated for 0.25 W. If your circuit draws more than about 150 mA, the resistor is going to get too hot.

[image]

You mention 1.9 A in the inductor, so it seems like your circuit will be drawing more current than that little resistor can handle.

Answer (score 4):

The AC mains comes in and is rectified to nodes which are mistakenly called neutral and live which they surely are not. The rectifier negative output will surely go down to peak negative voltage with respect to earth.

That same neutral is connected to GND symbol. So if it is correct, it makes the whole circuit that is referenced to the same GND node be basically live with mains and is not safe to touch or connect to any other earth referenced equipment.

The resistor is also likely too small wattage to handle the load anyway, but it did act as a fuse so it may have protected everyrthing else from further damage.

With that found and all the other small flaws found by other people, it likely won't work and likely is not safe to use.

Comment: There is a lovely bit of doings down in the bottom left of the (awful) schematic of the primary side switching, where 'neutral' (It is nothing of the sort) is connected to an Earth that has somehow snuck into the isolated floating bit of the switcher. Also, on the board I don't think you make the required safety isolation distances.

Comment: I am an Electronics engineer and need to develop a electrical thing for a project. So my knowledge in these aspects are a bit low but tried. Any best guidelines or reference for these kind of supplies you guys can suggest?